# What can I change to make this code work with all section elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, mern

so I got this code that is adding a class-name when the section is in the viewport, so far it only works with the first element since I'm using querySelector, but if I chance to querySelectorAll it does not work.

What I'm trying is to add animation to every section while the user is scrolling through the page, whether up or down.

```
import React from 'react';

const EffectComponent = () => {
  const vpPlitz = (element) => {
    const scroll = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    const boundsTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + scroll;

    const viewport = {
      top: scroll,
      bottom: scroll + window.innerHeight,
    };

    const bounds = {
      top: boundsTop,
      bottom: boundsTop + element.clientHeight,
    };

    return (
      (bounds.bottom >= viewport.top && bounds.bottom <= viewport.bottom) ||
      (bounds.top <= viewport.bottom && bounds.top >= viewport.top)
    );
  };

  // Usage.
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const answer = document.querySelector('section');

    const handler = () => {
      return vpPlitz(answer)
        ? answer.classList.add('section-animated')
        : answer.classList.remove('section-animated');
    };

    handler();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handler);
  });

  return null;
};

export default EffectComponent;
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Thet's help I was able to change the React. I'm posting it if someone may have use of it.

````
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const EffectComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const answers = document.querySelectorAll('section');

    const handler = (answer) => {
      return vpPlitz(answer)
        ? answer.classList.add('section-animated')
        : answer.classList.remove('section-animated');
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      answers.forEach((answer) => handler(answer));
    });
  }, []);

  const vpPlitz = (element) => {
    const scroll = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    const boundsTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + scroll;

    const viewport = {
      top: scroll,
      bottom: scroll + window.innerHeight,
    };

    const bounds = {
      top: boundsTop,
      bottom: boundsTop + element.clientHeight,
    };

    return (
      (bounds.bottom >= viewport.top && bounds.bottom <= viewport.bottom) ||
      (bounds.top <= viewport.bottom && bounds.top >= viewport.top)
    );
  };

  return null;
};

export default EffectComponent;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelectorAll() returns an Array of elements, so, if you want to add or remove classes to each elements, you need to loop though the Array. For example,

```
    const answers - document.querySelectorAll('section');
    const handler = (answer) => {
       return vpPlitz(answer)
            ? answer.classList.add('section-animated')
            : answer.classList.remove('section-animated');
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll',() => {
       answers.forEach(answer => handler(answer));
   })
```

you also should remove the event listeners when the component is unmounted. You can use the event listener: **beforeunload**. In it run the exact same function that you ran for DOMContentloaded but replace `window.addEventListener('scroll', handler(answer)` with `window.removeEventListener('scroll', handler(answer)`.

Comment: Hi, your code is good, but is adding the classname to all the section elements, what I want is that the classname will be added only when the a section is in the viewport.

Comment: I just showed you the part you need to replace. I didn't necessarily have to rewrite the same code you have before that doesn't need changing. So, the part I wrote is inside the DOMContentLoaded callback function. I thought you'd understand that.

Comment: Btw, if you're using react, why are you using DOMContentLoaded listener? When you can just use componentDidMount life cycle method.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did, I understood, but that's what I'm getting, all the section are loading with the class now.

Comment: Well, I'm kinda new using react, so I'm not totally sure a better way to do it

Comment: I've updated the code, pleas try it again. If that's not working, please provide me with all your codes in codesandbox.

Comment: here is the react doc about classes and lifecyle hooks, if you want ot learn about it. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks to your guidance I changed the component to react. I'm using hooks, I added an answer with the new code.

Comment: That's great. Keep up!. And try to avoid using DOM directly as much as you can, if you're using react. React pretty much offers almost everything that document property offers.

Comment: You also need to clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted. Luckly, you can do it inside useEffect hooks. Here is the documentation - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html  . I hope you can update you're answer better with this. I can also help, I you want. But I want you to try it yourself first.